# Move files and folder without removing folder structure of source folder

Tags: bash, command, mv

What I am trying to accomplish is to move files (and sub-folders) as they are being added into a specific folder but I want to keep the original folder structure in both source and destination. I believe this is easily explained with an example. Imagine the following folder/files structure:

```
/source/foo/bar1
/source/bar2
/dest
```

And I want to archive the following folder/files structure.

```
/source/foo
/dest/foo/bar1
/dest/bar2
```

Is there a way to do this, that can be automated?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rsync` to copy everything, and then delete everything except directories from the source. For example, starting with this (a `source` directory containing the file `bar2` and the subdirectory `foo` which contains the file `source/foo/bar2`):

```
$ tree source/
source/
├── bar2
└── foo
    └── bar1

1 directory, 2 files
```

You would run:

```
rsync -r source/ dest/
```

Which creates:

```
    $ tree dest/
dest/
├── bar2
└── foo
    └── bar1

1 directory, 2 files
```

And now delete any non-directories from `source`:

```
find source/ -not -type d -delete
```

Or, if your `find` doesn't have `-delete`, use:

```
find source/ ! -type d -exec rm {} +
```

---

To automate it, you would just write a little script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

source="$1"
dest="$2"

rsync -r "$source"/ "$dest"/ 
find "$source"/ -not -type d -delete
```

Make the script executable and run it with the source and dest directories as arguments:

```
foo.sh /source /dest
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of work for your OS to do. You could move the whole thing. Then copy back just the directory structure (apparently this says how https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960021/537980 )

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor moving only makes sense if source and dest are on the same filesystem. If not, there's no benefit over copying. You can tell rsync to delete copied files, restart from where it left off, check md5sum etc. It is a far more sophisticated tool than `mv` so unless we know that this will always be on the same filesystem, I don't see any benefit in moving first and then recreating the structure. It would just make for a much more complex solution for little benefit (if on the same filesystem) or no benefit. Plus, it's inelegant! Deleting just to recreate rubs me the wrong way :)